# Locked out of Wordpress website from wrong amount of login attempts

Tags: admin, login

I tried logging in to my Wordpress website and got the login wrong a couple of times. After a 3rd or 4th time I am unable to see my Wordpress website at all. I can't even see the front page of it. Is there a way I can see if I was blocked through my server? I am hosting on DigitalOcean using a Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Wordpress using a one-click solution on DigitalOcean and found out that it was on their side that they block IP's on malicious attempts. I found out that `fail2ban` was the reason why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed a firewall plugin? Your IP seems to be blocked. I suggest you to turn your modem off and on again to obtain new IP and try login Wordpress again.